# Create own implementation of vector which has moving operations and push_back for rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, vectors

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    T* buffer;
public:
    Vector(size_t s) {
        size = 0;
        capacity = s;       
        buffer = new T[capacity];
    }
    //Move constructor
    Vector(Vector&& rhs): size(rhs.size),
                          capacity(rhs.capacity),
                          buffer(tmp.buffer)
    {
        rhs.buffer = nullptr;
    }
    T& operator=(Vector&& tmp) {
        size = tmp.size;
        capacity = tmp.capacity;
        buffer = std::move(tmp.buffer);
        return *this;
    }
    void push_back(const T& v) {
        if (size >= capacity)
            reserve(capacity + 5);
        buffer[size++] = v;
    }
    void push_back(T&& v) {
        if (size >= capacity)
            reserve(capacity + 5);
        buffer[size++] = v;
    }
```

Have I implemented all move operations in my class Vector?
Is it correct implementation of method push_back for rvalue ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We don't check for correctness of the code. Please refer to [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) if you have further questions. Also, your vector default constructs everything. You need to use uninitialized memory, aka Heil malloc.

Comment: Have you tested the code? It's up to you to tell us if the code works correctly.

Comment: Put on hold because `buffer(tmp.buffer)` in the move constructor won't compile.

Comment: Your assignment leaks. Have a read of this: http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/27/vector/  I prefer using the swap technique for move semantics. It delays destruction of resources thus potentially allowing re-use.

Answer (score 1):

> Have I implemented all move operations in my class Vector?

Yes. And no. You have a bug. You are not resetting the size of the moved `Vector`, but resetting its buffer, which can break code like this:

```
Vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
Vector<int> v = std::move(vec);
if (vec.size() == 1)
    vec[0] = 8; // undefined behavior!
```

Also, what is `tmp`? Did you mean to use `rhs`?

> Is it correct implementation of method push_back for rvalue ?

No. In

```
buffer[size++] = v;
```

you are not taking advantage that `v` is a rvalue reference. You are copying `v` into the buffer, but that is not needed, as `v` points to a rvalue. You can move it to the buffer:

```
buffer[size++] = std::move(v);
```

---

Although you have implemented all move operations for `Vector`, you forgot the copy operations. But maybe you just hide them because you didn't want any feedback on them.

Nonetheless, you could have written your move constructor like this, which is more readable IMO (and doesn't include the bug mentioned above):

```
Vector(Vector&& rhs) : size(std::exchange(rhs.size, 0)),
                       capacity(std::exchange(rhs.capacity, 0)),
                       buffer(std::echange(rhs.buffer, nullptr))
{}
```

You can do the same thing for `operator=(Vector&&)`.

However, consider using the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), for a exception safe way of implementing the Rule of Five.